# ELB redirect traffic from one port to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Can AWS ELB redirect traffic from one port to another? Take this example - I have an application running on 8445 but I only want to expose port 443. I have tried this with target groups and listeners but no joy.

Thanks!

Comment: You want the ELB to expose 443 and connect to 8445 on your target? That's a standard feature of ELBs.

Comment: Yup. How is it implemented? I can't seem to find any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up an ELB to listen on a port (443 in your case) and redirecting it to a target group using a different port (8445) is straightforward and well-documented.

**Step 1 Create a Target Group**

In the EC2 GUI click on `Target Groups` --> `Create Target Groups`

Fill in the form as shown below and `Create`

[image]

On the same screen click on the `Targets` tab and click `Edit`

Fill out the form as shown below following these steps:

1. Click the target host box(ex) you want load balanced
2. Click `Add to registered` button
3. Click `Save`

[image]

**Step 2 - Create a Load Balancer and attach Target**

In the EC2 GUI click on `Load Balancers` --> `Create Load Balancer`
Next, select the type of LB you want.  In this example, I chose `Network Load Balancer`

Give it a name and fill in the form as below.  Next, choose the Load Balancer Protocol (most likely TLS(secure TCP) If this is externally facing the availability zones you select should be public. When complete click `Configure Security Settings`

[image]

The next step is to select and/or upload the certificate you'll be using for TLS.

After that, you'll `Configure Routing`.  Choose an Existing Target Group and pick the group you created in Step 1 above. When complete click on `Next: Register Targets`

[image]

The Register Targets screen should show the targets you registered in Step 1. To proceed click `Review` then click `Create`

**NOTE:**  The target host(s) you selected should allow the ELB access to the port you selected on the host security group, in this case, port 8445.

If you did all these steps and it's still not working, please supply more details on how it's not working and we can troubleshoot that.

**References**

[Network Load Balancers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYhtr.png)

Comment: Images in this answer can't be viewed